# How do you view session cookies in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, session-cookies

I am able to see session cookies in Firefox 3.6 by going to

> Tools->Options->Privacy->Remove Individual Cookies

How do I see those same session cookies in IE (6/7/8)?

> Tools->Internet Options->Browsing
>   history Settings->View files

only contains persistent cookies

Also how do I access them programmatically? In Firefox I use the `nsICookieManager` interface to read the session cookies, does IE contain an equivalent interface?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Cookies set with the `HTTPOnly` attribute will not be visible to Javascript (e.g. via the `document.cookie` accessor). In IE8, 9, and 10, hit F12 to open the Developer Tools. Click Cache > View Cookie Information to see persistent and session cookies that apply to the current domain.

This feature is not present in the IE11 version of the tools, which would mean that your choices are 1> Watch outbound Cookie headers in Fiddler or on the Network tab, or 2> Write a plugin that calls the `InternetGetCookieEx` API with the appropriate flag to include `HTTPOnly` cookies.

Comment: I'm able to see session cookies using developer tools. I'm not able to see HTTPOnly cookies though.

Answer (score 6):

Type into adress-bar:

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie)
```

to see the cookies that are currently readable by javascript.

Regarding to the  read/write of session-cookies:
Why do you need to do it using javascript? usually session-cookies are needed to have an relation to serverside stored data, so you need to manage the cookies from serverside, no matter what browser there may be.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the cookies I'm working with aren't stored in document.cookie.

I'm working from a browser plugin context and I need to be able to persist these cookies out to file.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can set HTTP-only cookies, these explicitly **do not** show up in `document.cookie`. It is possible to have two cookies with the same name like this so this can cause some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

F12-> Network Tab -> Enable Network Capture Traffic Capturing - > Details Tab -> Request Header Tab.

[image: Snap Shot]