# How to view session cookies in internet explorer7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, session-cookies

In Firefox, we can easily view session cookies using the browser toolbar
I have already reviewed [How do you view session cookies in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051811/how-do-you-view-session-cookies-in-internet-explorer) But that applies to IE8+. 
How do I view session cookies in IE7 from the browser toolbar??? Or without any external tools???

Answer (score 0):

[Download the developer toolbar for IE-7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) and then go to `Tools- Toolbars - Explorere Bar - IE Developer Toolbar`. At the bottom you will see the `IE Developer toolbar`. Click on `Cache - View Cookie information`.