# View HttpOnly session cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, session-cookies, ie-developer-tools

Using Internet Options I can see all persistent cookies, and using Developer Tools I can see all JS-accessible session cookies. There does not seem to be a way to view HTTPOnly session cookies.

In Firefox there are many options, both built-in and with Firebug, to view cookies, including being able to see the request/response headers. Is there no way in IE8 to see HTTPOnly session cookies?

Related questions (no solutions for HttpOnly):
[IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763621/how-to-view-session-cookies-in-internet-explorer7) [IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051811/how-do-you-view-session-cookies-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/06/04/understanding-the-new-wininet-flag-internet-cookie-httponly.aspx

Comment: any reason why you wouldn't use IE10 set to IE8 mode? Or is there a reason you believe IE8 isn't handling your specific session cookie the right way?

Comment: Because I don't have IE10, and many people who's sessions I debug also don't.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/06/04/understanding-the-new-wininet-flag-internet-cookie-httponly.aspx

> There are a couple of new Cookie flags introduced with the Internet
>   Explorer 8 WinInet.dll.  The INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY flag allows you
>   to read the HttpOnly cookies in your WinInet Code.  This flag is
>   documented here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384714(VS.85).aspx.

and here's a way to build a tool and use this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38616/Retrieve-HttpOnly-Session-Cookie-in-WebBrowser

Off the IE8 shelf not sure I see a way to retrieve HTTPOnlyCookies, since the dev tools seems to show only non HTTPOnly cookies. If you want to use a tool, use Fiddler2 and set response type to HTTPOnly.

Comment: So you have to write your own plugin?

Comment: I havent found anything off the IE shelf yet, or you could try using Fiddler and set response to HTTPOnly