# how to view httponly cookies in IE8

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8

I know how to view cookies in IE8, which is described under [How do you view session cookies in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051811/how-do-you-view-session-cookies-in-internet-explorer)
but is there any way to view "httponly" cookies in IE8?

Comment: Are you sure they don't show up there?

Comment: Apparently not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935211/view-httponly-session-cookies-in-internet-explorer

Comment: oops...ie8 really sucks!

Comment: I changed my website's access from port 3000 to port 80, and the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use Fiddler; allow you to view all Request and Response data.

Comment: I've tried Fiddler2,but it seems that there's some other problem: I've seen the Set-Cookie Header in the response headers section which is used to store the session id, but it's not working --- that's why I hope to find some way to see if the cookie is properly set.

Comment: Check the cookies tab for the Response that sets your cookie. 
Your cookie should have a "HttpOnly", e.g.

Set-Cookie: acad=zWp; expires=Wed, 21-Aug-2013 05:19:54 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: I've had checked that, and the response was just ok. Actually, the problem I came across seems to be caused by domain port. I used Port 3000 for local testing, and this leaded to the failure, which means that in ie8 set-cookie can only work fine with port-80-hosts, I guess..