# How to know cookie expiry time in Internet Explorer(IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I know that its not possible to read expires value from document.cookie.Its possible to read the value in Firefox and  Chrome easily from there options/settings.But older versions of IE(6 & 7) don't provide such an interface to read expire value (I am not sure about the latest versions).

So, how can I know when a cookie is going to expire in IE.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6051811/851604

Comment: I need to see the expiry time on older versions of IE, which is not what the link you posted is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not through javascript.

But why would you need to? You can just set it again, in which case the expiry time is reset.

Comment: I am writing cross browser code and I need to be sure if cookies are created with correct expiry or not. Older browsers may have some issues, I don't know, but I needed to be sure. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think incorrect timeouts have ever been a problem. Besides, cookies should only be helpers. It shouldn't be a problem is they expire a day early. And IE6 is old and dead, as will be IE7 soon. You shouldn't waste time getting it to run in those browsers. If it works it's nice, but don't waste hours on a thing like this.

Comment: Well I need to consider older versions till they are used as I said its a cross browser code which may be running on any browser.

Comment: Yay! Good old "Any browser". How about my copy of Netscape Navigator 3, then?  ;-)  Seriously though: Saying "any browser" is futile these days. Sure, support IE6 and IE7 if you *must*, but specify that they're your lowest; don't pretend that "any" browser will work. I do agree with GolezTrol though; supporting IE6 is futile unless you have a specific need for it and IE7 is rapidly going the same way.

Comment: @Spudley. I couldn't have put it better although I was tempted to make the same NN3 remark. :) Of course there are always reasons to keep support for such old browsers, and it greatly depends on your target audience. But if I look in Google Analytics for a website of mine, only 33% is using IE and only 0.07% of that used IE6. That's only 6 of the 27000 visitors last month. If I compare that to 1250 Android users, I know where my testing and compatibility efforts should be.

Comment: @GolezTrol - Yep. Far more Android users than IE6. And iOS, even Blackberry has more. Also, I'd be willing to bet that the OP's "all browsers" doesn't include screen readers for accessibility users either.

Comment: @ Spudley-
Yeah, IE 6 and 7 is the lowest.
I agree that they have much less share, but in total (IE6 and IE7) share is around 8% (Wikipedia says so) and if my code is run by many clients, on many websites which can get traffic from IE 6 and 7 also, then its crucial.

Comment: Of which 7.7% is IE7. At least drop IE6. Support from Microsoft has stopped too, earlier this year. It is officially dead (in contrast to IE7).

Comment: "Support for IE6 in all versions of Windows prior to XP has expired. Extended support only for Windows XP until April 8, 2014" - WIKIPEDIA