# How does one view the RequestVerificationToken cookie in Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

I'm using APS.NET MVC 5 and am getting this error during an Ajax post with Internet Explorer 11:

```
The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L1JldkNvbm5lY3Q1" is not present.
```

This error only occurs with IE 11 (it doesn't occur with Chrome) and it only occurs on the server (it doesn't doesn't occur when debugging locally with IE).

From what I can tell, the cookie does not actually ever exist in IE, as the cookie does not appear in the INetCache folder, located here:

```
C:\Users\[myusername]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
```

This folder is supposed to store all cookies for IE 11, and there are a lot of cookies in there, but I don't see the RequestVerificationToken cookie and thus I think this might be the cause of the error.

I can see the RequestVerificationToken cookie in Chrome, but not in IE 11.  Am I just incorrect in my method for finding cookies in IE?  Is this the wrong folder possibly?

How does one view the RequestVerificationToken cookie in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the specified folder does _not_ contain all cookies. Some security-sensitive cookies are sent with an `HTTPSOnly` flag, meaning they're only sent over secure connections and not written to disk unencrypted. There are other edge-cases and variations on this theme. Far easier to use the network tools (F12), or Wireshark/similar to see what's actually being sent back/forth

Comment: In IE11 Developer Tools, under the Network tab, when I click on the Ajax POST line, and then on the Cookies tab (to the right), it states "This resource has no cookies".  When I do these same steps in Chrome Developer Tools, however, the cookie is present in the POST line.

Comment: Have you tried typing `document.cookie` into the console? Should dump the values that javascript is allowed to view (again, secure cookies follow slightly different rules here). If you can see where the cookie header is being sent (to you, originally), you should be able to see what flags/domain are being set and possibly see what the problem is.

Comment: When I click on the Console tab in Developer Tools and type in "document.cookie" and hit enter, the response is two quotation marks: ""  This happens in both IE11 and Chrome.  I tried refreshing the page that has issues, and typing in "document.cookie" again, but the results were the same.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting this then... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053831/156755

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the issue, because I just checked IE11 when running the application locally (localhost) and the cookie is visible in IE11 Developer Tools.  So the cookie is visible when running locallly (and the underlying error doesn't occur), but the cookie is not visible when the app is running on the server (Windows Server 2012, IIS).

Comment: When you're running locally, are you using https with a valid SSL certificate? (And are you doing so remotely?)

Comment: When running locally I'm using http.

Comment: And when published to a remote server?

Comment: When published to the remote server, where this error is occurring, the application is using https and IE11 and Chrome report no ssl issues.

Comment: [Edit: ignore the previous text in this comment, there is only one GET now]

Comment: The RequestVerificationToken cookie is set in the GET request.

Comment: Yeah, the point I was trying to make is that some cookies behave differently when issued over HTTP and HTTPS. By default, Javascript can't access "secure" cookies, although the browser should be adding them in itself. First up, create yourself a self-sign SSL certificate and use it on your local server. Then, you can verify if I'm right about the problem (and if so, will have a local test environment that reproduces the problem).

Comment: I disabled https and the issue was still present.  Locally, the cookie is visible in the POST request, but it's not visible when acessing the application on the server.  Odd issue, but I haven't given up.